# Make part of a <select> dropdown input option underlined with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to underline part of the text in an input field only using CSS.

I can underline the entire `option` by adding the `text-decoration: underline` to the `select` element like so:

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```
<select name="id" id="products" class="underline">
  <option value="val1">my value 1</option>
  <option value="val2">my value 2</option>
  <option value="val3">my value 3</option>
</select>
```

I tried wrapping a `span` tag on the innerText of the `option` element text I'm interested in and adding the same class to the span element..

```
<select name="id" id="products">
  <option value="val1">my <span class="underline">value 1</span></option>
  <option value="val2">my <span class="underline">value 2</span></option>
  <option value="val3">my <span class="underline">value 3</span></option>
</select>
```

.. but this doesn't have the desired effect as it seems you can't style `option` elements.

Is there a way to achieve this without using Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 2022, I do not believe this is possible.  If we look at the [MDN reference page for the `<option/>` element, we see that the "permitted content" section notes that an option is allowed to contain:

> Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

As such, MDN's reference implies that inclusion of any HTML elements such as a `<span/>` would be disallowed by the spec.  This is most likely why browsers do not style it as you would expect-- from the browser's perspective, it doesn't expect any such content because it is forbidden.

The only way I could see this being *perhaps* possible without JS would be if you could find sufficient unicode characters to use in place of the plain characters using some online tool like [Yay Text Unicode Underline](https://yaytext.com/underline/)-- with this tool I was able to get `"Value 3"` underlined in a few different styles, like:

> v̲a̲l̲u̲e̲ ̲3̲

Obviously, this is solution is far from ideal-- it is not certain to work or be have wide browser compatibility, and I suspect it would be a difficult development undertaking.

Most likely, if this is a critical requirement, you'll have to look at creating a similar component using HTML, CSS, and JS.  If you take this route, I recommend you use an online example from the W3 showing how to create an accessible component, such as this [collapsible listbox example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html)-- this way you can be certain that your resulting UI is appropriately accessible to those using keyboards, screen readers, or other assistive technologies.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation Alexander!
What would a javascript solution for this look like?

Comment: @ijome - you are welcome :)  The "collapsible listbox example" link in the question is on W3's site -- it is effectively an accessible dropdown built using a combination of `<ul/>`s, `<li/>`s, and `<button/>`s with proper `role` attributes and JS to handle interactions.  Because it is using `<li/>` as a stand-in for `<option/>`, you are less restricted in what content it can contain, and can style it much more liberally than is possible with an `<option/>`.  That example contains all the code-- you could start from there and adjust as needed.